# Is server side rendering suitable for mobile apps?

Tags: mobile, next.js, server-rendering

I am considering building my react app with the intent of having both web and mobile built . I came across [Next js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/) and is thinking of using it. However, what bothers me is that considering server side rendering is rendered in the server, would that be suitable for mobile apps ? I mean what happens to my mobile app when offline ? Is server side rendering applicable in mobile apps? Am i confusing how the server rendering works ? Pls a better explanation is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Server side rendering javascript apps gives the same result as any other server-side language.

An example could be a static site made only by html files. What would happen when offline? Nothing.
This behavior is due to impossibility to connect to host.

To handle offline for mobile apps you could have static file handled in app, or you could use a more modern approach without developing the mobile app: PWA.

A Progressive Web App allows to integrate with some native functions of mobile devices and to handle offline status.